# Likely RS-485 color coding of three wires?

Tags: rs485, colour-coding

We received a piece of equipment (actually from an Italian manufacturer, if that gives a hint) which uses RS-485.

So, as well as a power connection the devices have THREE WIRES (bare wires) coming from the relevant board, being **white, gray, black**.

We have all the custom communications protocol in a PDF, but they neglected to include a mention of the wiring of the RS-485.

Can you guess which is **A, B, Reference**?

Is there a **typical color scheme** for the three, for "raw" 485 wires?

As it happens the engineers are completely **on holiday** for a week! (Typical production hang-up right?) Also just generally curious if there is a **typical standard** for this.

Just FTR if relevant, the plan by us and them was that the three wires would connect to a convertor to RS-232 and hence to an ordinary (ie Windows8) PC; cable lengths are only a meter or two.

Comment: Can you trace them to a chip?

Comment: Ignacio -- Not quite, just to the connector on a board.  In any event, I was curious if there is a **typical color scheme** here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joe - forget about hopes of finding a standard color scheme.

The simplest thing is that the Reference (Common) lead will connect to the GND of the circuit. That should be dead simple to discover which one with a multi-meter.

Finding that the other two will be the A and B lines. Hook those up one way and see if any protocol makes sense. If not then hook them up the other way.

Comment: Thanks Michael, looks like the definitive answer. Cheers.